# Shell script to find only IP addresses from hosts file using hostname on windows

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a text file with hostnames and I am trying to find the list of IPs associated with these hostnames respectively and dump the output to a CSV , I am using the below powershell script but it gives me a lot of results but I only need the IP address.

Code:

```
$address = Get-Content ".\server_list.txt"

foreach ($i in $address) {
    $i + "`n" + "=========================="
    [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($i) 
}
```

it gives me output in below format.

```
hostname.com
==========================

Address            : 12345678
AddressFamily      : InterNetwork
ScopeId            : 
IsIPv6Multicast    : False
IsIPv6LinkLocal    : False
IsIPv6SiteLocal    : False
IsIPv6Teredo       : False
IsIPv4MappedToIPv6 : False
IPAddressToString  : 10.x.x.x
```

I only need the IPaddressToString value, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($i).IPAddressToString` should do the trick